# How can I make a glowing iris (eye) material similar to these pictures?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor

Is it possible to create such a material in Blender?

[image][image]
[image]

Thank you in advance!

My nodes of iris:[image]
[image]

Comment: Hello :). Sure, it is indeed possible. What have you tried so far and where *exactly* are you stuck?

Comment: Using compositing?

Comment: use emission and set strength higher than 1

Comment: In this area I'm still a beginner of creating materials and I have no idea how this should work so that it looks something like in the pictures so I ask here

Answer (score 3):

Here is a file and a screen shot - I extruded my circle and then applied scale and transformation (ctrl-A) before unwrapping the mesh and choosing Follow Active Quads and Even so that they would align liek you see in the lower left.
Then I made up a material to use a texture to stencil between the shaders to get emission area showing.
[image]

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1m-ZLTv5bUzeDT5XOHaVbgBRGhAtu8maB/view?usp=sharing